# I can't change the font in python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

when I input : `from docx.enum Import WD_STYLE_TYPE`

the output is:   `from docx.enum import WD_STYLE_TYPE ImportError: cannot import name 'WD_STYLE_TYPE' from 'docx.enum'`

I already had problems installing python-docx that solved

Answer (score 1):

It should be imported from `docx.enum.style`

```
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
```